# group by and FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, path

having trouble using xml to path and group by in sql server

i have this table:

[image]

thank you

need to get this:

[image]

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: i couldn't add a text instead of image it got ruined

Comment: Why would you want a space before `'gig'` but not before `'gama'`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i dont mind the space.. i just need it to be in the same cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that these 3 columns come from the same table.
I created your given data, so I could test if my solution works. And it does :)

```
create table table1 (column1 int, column2 nvarchar(1), column3 nvarchar(150))


insert into table1 values (1, 'A', 'Alpha')
, (1, 'b', 'beta')
, (1, 'b', 'gama')
, (2, 'A', 'delta')
, (2, 'b', 'ef')
, (2, 'b', 'gig')


SELECT 
   t1.column1
   , t1.column2
   , STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.column3 
          FROM table1 t2
          WHERE t2.column1 = t1.column1
            and t2.column2 = t1.column2
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as new_row
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.column1, t1.column2
ORDER BY 1
```