# Using GROUP BY with FOR XML PATH in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, for-xml-path

I am trying to

1. group by ID and
2. aggregate multiple comments into a single row

Right now, I can do the no. 2 part for a single ID (`ID = 1006`), but I would like to aggregate comments for all IDs. I am struggling where and how to add "group by" clause in my query.

Here is the query:

```
create table Comments (ID int, Comment nvarchar(150), RegionCode int)


insert into Comments values (1006, 'I', 1)
, (1006, 'am', 1)
, (1006, 'good', 1)
, (1006, 'bad', 2)
, (2, 'You', 1)
, (2, 'are', 1)
, (2, 'awesome', 1)


SELECT 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT Comment
               FROM Comments
               WHERE ID = 1006 AND RegionCode != 2
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 999999) AS Comment_Agg
```

My desired result looks something like this:

[image]

FYI, I am using `FOR XML PATH` here to aggregate multiple comments into a single row because `STRING_AGG` function is not supported in my version - SQL Server 2016 (v13.x).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [group by and FOR XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728202/group-by-and-for-xml-path)

Comment: You basically can't do normal aggregation, you need to requery the table in the subquery (although it can be corellated) So for example `SELECT c.Comment FROM Comments c2 WHERE c2.ID = c.ID FOR XML PATH`. If you post your full query we can have a go

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: @Charlieface I just edited the query with a reproducible example. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I just edited the query with a reproducible example. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: #3, desired output is still missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID int, Comment nvarchar(150));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
(1006, 'I'),
(1006, 'am'),
(1006, 'good'),
(2, 'You'),
(2, 'are'),
(2, 'awesome');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT p.ID
   , STUFF((SELECT @separator + Comment 
          FROM @tbl AS c
          WHERE c.ID = p.ID
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(@separator), '') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.ID;
```

**Output**

```
+------+-----------------+
|  ID  |     Result      |
+------+-----------------+
|    2 | You are awesome |
| 1006 | I am good       |
+------+-----------------+
```